# Is it possible to set an element to display only when the <img> element is removed?

Tags: html

For printing purposes, I removed the IMG element, but I wanted an H1 element to be displayed on another portion of the site when the IMG element is removed.

Is this possible?

Comment: When the `<img>` element removes, any action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS [media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) for this.

Don't think of it as revealing one element when another is removed; instead think of it as selectively displaying elements depending on whether they are for print or screen.

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media print {
    .screenonly { display: none; }
}
@media screen {
    .printonly { display: none; }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class=printonly>Header for print</h1>
<h1 class=screenonly>Header for screen</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Save this to a file and view it in a browser, and you will only see "Header for screen".  Print the same page and you will instead see "Header for print".

This technique will work on any element and can be used to set any CSS style for print or screen.

Comment: Thanks alot dude =D . This is the solution I have been looking for.